# ICT Bill Accepter

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, c++, led

I have a ICT a6-15scp-usd4-ii. I have all of the wires for it. I dont have the gambling machine it came out of and it was laying around. Is it possible to make a Light come on when a bill is put in? Can it be wired to the arduino to act as a switch per-say? If more info is needed let me know. I will make a tutorial for this if it works.

Comment: Bill acceptors are notoriously hard to work with because usually the datasheet and or manual are usually only available under NDA. You will probably just have to reverse engineer it.

Comment: ill give it a shot, but it is not looking good.

Comment: Looking at the only doc I can find, http://www.ict-america.com/docs/a6v6/A6.V6-MXP4.pdf it looks like if you have the A6 version there is an RS232 port somewhere, which means the most you would have to do is level translation. If you have the V6 it will be using MDB, which is typically a 9-bit UART. There is an implementation of MDB found here: https://github.com/MarginallyClever/MDB-Sniffer

Comment: What kind of interface does your model have? Because when you have RS232 it should be fairly simple to see what it'll print out when you enter bills into it.

Comment: frst you're going to have to send an command to the bill acceptor to tell it to accept bills, they you just need to find the wire that pulses when a bill is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Go to ICT's website to download the Installation manual (one used for many different models), there is info on the pinout for every pin on your model, along with recommended I/O interface circuit.

I am using a different model, but from what I know, if your model is a "Pulse" model, which means that when a bill is accepted, there are pulses that you can captured (the pulse width is pre-set by toggle switches, and the number of pulses depends on the value of the bill).

What I would do is to use interrupt to listen to these pulses. When the interrupt triggers, light up your LED.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is an old post, but I have interfaced with a BV20, and noticed most of the ICT validator's have a "busy" line that is asserted whenever the unit is transporting, validating, or storing/stacking a bill.  If you want to light something up when a bill is being handled, but not necessarily validated, that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

ICT a6-15scp-usd4-ii is a pulse/parallel bill acceptor. [Here is the datasheet](https://na.suzohapp.com/images/pdf/a6v6.pdf), the link in the comments is broken. A6 version uses pulse/parallel protocol (V6 version is MDB). The 110V version that you use has only pulse protocol.

Take care with the wiring, the acceptor uses dangerous  110VAC voltage.

I understand you want to make same kind of pay per time device like those used in kiddie rides machines.

There are many examples on the internet on connecting a pulse bill acceptor to Arduino. The theory is simple the bill acceptor has a PULSE output, usually in negative logic, high in idle, that send a low pulse for each monetary unit, 1 for 1$, 5 for 5$ and so on.

Sometimes, like in your case, the bill acceptor has an enable input through which you can enable or disable the acceptance. But in A6 110V this input must be connected to hot 110v lines so it's harder to handle through Arduino so you will need to use a relay or to leave-it active all the time by setting dip SW 8 to ON, see page 6 and page 9 in the manual.

**The electrical connections.**

See the connector pinout , page 5[image]

The credit (pulse) output uses an optocoupler so it has two lines CREDIT_RELAY_COM (pin 1) on the above connector that must be connected to Arduino GND and CREDIT_RELAY(N.O.) (pin 16) that must be connected to the digital input of Arduino that read the pulses, this digital input must have a pull-up resistor to 5V, it might be the built in pull-up activated by using pinMode(PIN, INPUT_PULLUP) but better an external resistor 1k to 4.5k.

And, of course, the main power supply , pin 4 and pin 20 to main 110 voltage and don't forget the earth ground, pin 21 for safety.

**Bill acceptor dip switch settings**

See the page 6 of the manual. For the moment just put SW8 to ON (acceptor enabled) and all other to OFF (all bills enabled, one pulse one dollar, 50ms/50ms pulses)

**The Arduino source code**

To count the pulses from a pulse bill acceptor or coin acceptor there are many examples on the internet but I did one myself, very easy to use, [find the source code here](https://digielservice.wordpress.com/2021/02/17/billyone-bill-acceptor-on-arduino-with-source-code-jammer-proof-easiest-way/), that counts the pulses in background using timer1 interrupt. In this way the main loop is free for other tasks you need. You can strip the LCD part of the code if you don't use.

To work with ICT A6 you need to modify the some defines in the code: PULSE_WIDTH to 50 form 100 and PULSE_DELTA to at least 4 from 2 (because it's to small).

Connect Arduino A0 input to pin 16 (CREDIT RELAY) and to a pull-up resistor to 5V as I pointed above, and Arduino GND to pin 1 (CREDIT_RELAY_COM) and power the Arduino from some different source or through USB and the example should work now. Obviously the BILL_ACCEPTOR_ENABLE and BILL_ACCEPTOR_DISABLE macros will not work the acceptor is always enabled.

To actually make-it work as pay-per-time machine a suggestion of code will look like this:

```
unsigned long finish_time = 0;
#define MS_PER_DOLLAR 600000 //10 minutes
//add to setup 
turn_off_the_light();// Switch a pin or something

void loop(){
  unsigned long temp_millis;
  unsigned long temp_credits;
  temp_millis = millis()
  temp_credits = read_and_clear_pulses();
  if (finish_time < temp_millis) finish_time = temp_millis;
  finish_time += tempcredits * MS_PER_DOLLAR;
  if (finish_time > temp_millis)
     turn_on_the_light();
  else 
     turn_off_the_light();
// Do something else
}
```

If you use the device uninterrupted for more than 49 days you will have the millis rollover issue  but you can find examples on the internet how to handle this.